# three.js how to make texture "generated" texture coordinate, like blender cycles

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to display a texture onto a cylinder object in THREE.js, and I want to texture to show up on the cylinder in a well... not so distorted way, here's how it looks now: [image]

and that is just based off this simple texture:
[image]

I don't want it to be distorted / stretched along the edges of the cylinder, I would like it to look something like the "generated" texture coordinate in blender cycles:[image]

(notice the "box" setting in the image texture)

SOOO I have no idea how to set the texture coordinates in THREE.js ... ?

EDIT::: There's been a request for the actual source code, so here it is (even though it's complicated):

```
var COBY = new (function() {
 this.p = Processing;
 this.t=THREE;
 this.mouseX = 0;
 this.mouseY = 0;
  this.Keyboard = new (function() {
   this.keysDown = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
     this.keysDown[i] = false;
   }
   this.RIGHT = 39;
   this.LEFT = 37;
   this.UP = 38;
   this.DOWN = 40;
   this.setKeyDown = function(key) {
     COBY.Keyboard.keysDown[key] = true;
   };
   this.setKeyUp = function(key) {
     COBY.Keyboard.keysDown[key] = false;
   };
   this.isKeyDown = function(key) {
     return COBY.Keyboard.keysDown[key];
   };
 });
  document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
   COBY.Keyboard.setKeyDown(e.keyCode);


 };
  document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
   COBY.Keyboard.setKeyUp(e.keyCode);
 };
 document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
   COBY.mouseX = e.x;
   COBY.mouseY = e.y;
 };
 this.shapes = {
   cube:new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),
   cylinder: new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 1),
   plane: new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1,1),
 };
 this.textures = {
   white:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"white"}),
   red:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"red"}),
   purple:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"purple"}),
   blue:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"blue"}),
   pink:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"pink"}),
   gray:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"gray"}),
   yellow:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"yellow"}),
   green:new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"green"})
 };

this.loadTexture = function(name, path) {
  COBY.textures[name] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(path)
      });
  console.log(COBY.textures);
};

this.GUIContainer = function(obj) {
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.style.position="absolute";
    this.div.style.left=(obj.x || 0) + "px";
    this.div.style.top=(obj.y || 0) + "px";
    this.div.style.background=obj.color || "white";
    this.div.style.width = (obj.width || 100) + "px";
    this.div.style.height = (obj.height || 100) + "px";
    this.div.style.display = obj.invisible ? "none" : "block";
    var that = this;
    this.add = function(g) {
        that.div.appendChild(g.div);
    };
    if(document.body) {
        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    }
};

this.GUIObject = function(obj) {
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.style.position="absolute";
    this.div.style.left=(obj.x || 0) + "px";
    this.div.style.top=(obj.y || 0) + "px";
    this.div.style.background=obj.color || "white";
    this.div.style.width = (obj.width || 100) + "px";
    this.div.style.height = (obj.height || 100) + "px";
    if(obj.text) {
        this.div.innerHTML = "<p class='gTxt'>" + obj.text + "</p>";
    }
    if(obj.type === "button") {
        this.div.className = "btn";
    } 
};

this.Cobject = function(obj,world) {
 this.width=obj.width||1;
 this.height=obj.height||1;
 this.depth=obj.depth||1;
 this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
 this.rotation = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
 this.forReference = obj.forReference;
 if(obj.position) {
this.position.x = obj.position.x || 0;
this.position.y = obj.position.y || 0;
this.position.z = obj.position.z || 0;
 }
 if(obj.rotation) {
 this.rotation.x = obj.rotation.x || 0;
 this.rotation.y = obj.rotation.y || 0;
 this.rotation.z = obj.rotation.z || 0;
 }
 this.worldParent = world || false;
 this.followMouse = obj.followMouse || false;
 this.update=obj.update||function(c){};
 this.start = obj.start || function(){};
 this.texture = COBY.textures[obj.texture];
 //this.texture.wrapS = this.texture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;

 this.mesh=new THREE.Mesh(COBY.shapes[obj.shape],this.texture);
 var self = this;

 this.updateTexture = function(path) {
    self.mesh.material.map.image.src = path;
    self.mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
 }

 this.superUpdate = function(cob) {
   self.mesh.scale.set(self.width,self.height,self.depth);
   self.mesh.position.copy(self.position);
   self.mesh.rotation.set(self.rotation.x,self.rotation.y,self.rotation.z);
   self.update(cob);
 };


};
function webglAvailable() {
        try {
            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            return !!( window.WebGLRenderingContext && (
                canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) ||
                canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ) )
            );
        } catch ( e ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
this.World=function (obj) {
   this.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.height = window.innerHeight;
   this.loadTextures = function(texts) {
     for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
       COBY.loadTexture(texts[i].name, texts[i].path);
     }
   };

   if(obj) {
   this.width=obj.width || window.innerWidth;
   this.height=obj.height || window.innerHeight;
   if(obj.textures) {
     this.loadTextures(obj.textures);
   }
   }

   this.scene=new THREE.Scene();
   this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, this.width   / this.height, 0.1, 10000 );
   this.camera.name = "camera";
//if ( webglAvailable() ) {
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true});
//  } else {
    //  this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
//  }

this.renderer.setSize(this.width,this.height);
this.renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);

this.renderer.domElement.style.position="absolute";
this.renderer.domElement.style.left="0";
this.renderer.domElement.style.top="0";

this.camera.position.z=5;

this.cobs = [];
this.meshes=[];
var that=this;
this.light = function(x,y,z,inten) {
    var directionalLight1=new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight1.position.set(x,y,z,inten || 1);
    directionalLight1.name == "light";
    that.scene.add(directionalLight1);
};
this.lights = function() {
  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x606060 );
                that.scene.add( ambientLight );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 1, 0.75, -0.5 ).normalize();
                that.scene.add( directionalLight );
};
  this.lights();
this.add=function(obj){
   if(!obj.forReference) {
   if(obj.mesh) {
   that.scene.add(obj.mesh);
   that.meshes.push(obj.mesh);
   that.cobs.push(obj);
   } else {
    that.scene.add(obj);
   }



   }
   obj.start(obj);
};

this.cob = function(c) {
    that.add(new COBY.Cobject(c,that));
};

this.addCobjects = function(cobs) {
  for(var i = 0; i < cobs.length; i++) {
    that.add(new COBY.Cobject(cobs[i],that));
  }
};

this.empty = function() {
    that.meshes = [];
    that.cobs = [];
    for(var i = that.scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            that.scene.remove(that.scene.children[i]);
    }
    that.scene.add(that.camera);
    that.lights();
  console.log("just actually emptied..feels good");
};

this.update=function (){
  // noprotect
   for(var i=0;i<that.cobs.length;i++) {
    that.cobs[i].superUpdate(that.cobs[i]);
   }
   that.loop();
   that.renderer.render(that.scene, that.camera);
};
this.loop=function(){

};
this.canvas=this.renderer.domElement;


this.start = function(div) {
  if(!div)
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
  else
    div.appendChild(this.canvas);
  function sketchProc(proc) {
    // noprotect
      proc.draw=function(){    
         that.update();
      };
   }
   var procInst=new Processing(document.createElement("canvas"),sketchProc);
};
};
})();
```

Comment: It's not so clear about the cylinder. Is it a model, exported from blender, or you've created a custom geometry? Or is it a standard `THREE.CylinderGeometry()`/`THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry()`? Any chance to provide a live code example?

Comment: @prisoner849 standard THREE.CylinderGeometry()

Comment: Your screenshot is tiny, it is impossible to see what is going on there. Please post a bigger image. Like @prisoner849 demonstrated in his fine answer, the uv mapping of the default geometry is fine, so you most likely modified it in your code (scaling? ). Showing relevent bits of your code, or a snippet demonstrating the problem, would be great.

Comment: @Paul-Jan added source

Answer (score 2):

Both `THREE.CylinderGeometry()` and `THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry()` work as expected:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

//var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 1, 8);
var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(5, 5, 1, 8);

var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texEnd = texLoader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg");
texEnd.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texEnd.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texEnd.repeat.set(1, 1);
var texSide = texLoader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg");
texSide.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texSide.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texSide.repeat.set(1, 1 / (cylGeom.parameters.radiusTop * cylGeom.parameters.radiusBottom));

var cylMatEnd = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texEnd
});
var cylMatSide = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texSide
});
var cyl = new THREE.Mesh(cylGeom, [cylMatSide, cylMatEnd, cylMatEnd]);
scene.add(cyl);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: and BTW in the snippet the sides don't work how Iwould want it--non-repeating / squished

Comment: @user2016831 so, use two different material, one for ends and the other one for side. Use two deparated textures respectively.